# Camel FTPS Connection Login Failure

Tags: authentication, apache-camel, iis-6, ftps

I have IIS FTPS Server setup and am trying to connect from a Camel route. But I'm getting the error:

> 22 Sep 2019 08:59:51,650 | WARN  | Camel (Test) thread #202 -
>   ftps://test@test1834:21/BO/Salary | FtpConsumer | 248 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630347 | Cannot
>   connect/login to: ftps://test@test1834:21. Will skip this poll.

I can connect via FileZilla client and perform any read/write operation.

Credentials have been verified.

Camel-Core version 2.17.0

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

this flag "isImplicit=true" is no longer valid for Camel version 3.7.0
The new flag is "implicit=true"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the endpoint configuration, you probably should set the security mode `isImplicit=true`